# Failed to make rsyslog filter to particular file

Tags: rsyslog

I configure the rsyslog server with /var/rsyslog/foo.conf to accept the udp messages

```
$ModLoad imudp
$UDPServerRun 514
```

And try to filter the log contents start with "foo" to /var/log/foo.log. I have tried several filters.

```
:msg, contains, "foo" /var/log/foo.log
:msg, startswith, "foo" /var/log/foo.log
:msg, regex, "'^\s*foo.*" /var/log/foo.log
if $msg startswith 'foo' then /var/log/foo.log;
```

Nothing is working. I can get the proper in /vag/log/syslog but no way to filter it and output to foo.log. the message I got from syslog like this:

```
 2023-12-02T17:06:20.852836+00:00 foo
```

Which proves the udp and general logging are good. But no idea why the filters are not working.

my rsyslog server version is 8.2302.0 and the OS is Debian 12.

Comment: Have you restarted `syslog`? Was `/var/log/foo.log` automatically created after the restart?

Comment: Yes I did restart rsyslog (not syslog), but to my knowledge the syslog should be restarted with rsyslog together. And there was not foo.log automatically created after restarting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I debug the rsyslog and solved the problem.

the log got in the `/var/log/syslog` was:

```
2023-12-02T17:06:20.852836+00:00 foo
```

Which means the `foo` would be recognized as `source` not `msg`. To send message according to the RFC5424 format solves the problem:

```
echo -n "foo bar:foobar" | nc -w1 -u foo bar
```

in this case the syslog would log like hereunder:

```
2023-12-02T17:06:20.852836+00:00 foo bar: foobar
```

And the filter works fine.